# How to run my website as https which is running as Docker swarm cluster in AWS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssl, https

I am working on docker swarm and aws. I am not having much idea in it.
Please correct me if my question is wrong and kindly help me to solve my problem.

I have my docker swarm cluster running in AWS under a loadbalancer.
I created a certificate from Amazon certificate Manager for https to my load balancer.

In loadbalancer tab under listener if I set https for load balancer protocol and http to instance protocol like below, when I type https://website-url in the browser it automatically redirects to http.

`LoadBalancerProtocol LoadBalancerPort InstanceProtocol InstancePort Cipher SSL Certificate
     HTTPS              443              HTTP           80           Change 6e7528d6-8261-4d61-b1d3-3c2548e1b575 (ACM) Change`

But I want the website to be run as https not as http.
So I changed like below. That is making Instance port and its protocol as 443 and https.

`LoadBalancerProtocol LoadBalancerPort InstanceProtocol InstancePort Cipher SSL Certificate
     HTTPS              443              HTTPS          443          Change 6e7528d6-8261-4d61-b1d3-3c2548e1b575 (ACM) Change`

But After this https://website-url is continuously running without any response in the browser.

After doing some search, I came to know that ACM certificate only works for load balancer not for backend instance.

That is for instance level I need to enable https for apache.

The docker swarm cluster has 1 manager and 3 worker nodes. All the host instance OS is Alpine OS. The containers inside the nodes are Centos-7.
The containers are running as a service in the cluster.

Please guide me on this, 
Do I need to configure self signed certificate for apache inside the container or on the host instance.
I want my website to be run as https not http.

Kindly show me What are the steps required.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The load balancer port is what people talk to your load balancer on, so load balancer port 80 and 443 is correct.

The instance port is what port the load balancer talks to your webserver on. In this case for you both should be 80, unless your webserver is listening on 443 with a valid SSL cert (Not the case as you are using an AWS cert.)

Then in your code or your webserver what you need to do is check the X-Forwarded-Proto header http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/classic/x-forwarded-headers.html and if it's not https re-direct to https.
https://www.allcloud.io/how-to/how-to-force-https-behind-aws-elb/ has a couple examples.

Comment: Hi TheAnnihilator,
Thanks for the good point.
I looked at the link you mentioned and tried rewrite rule in .htaccess file in my code inside the docker container. But no response when I access the instance ip via browser `https://instance-ip`.
what should I do now?

Comment: If you are doing https directly to your instance IP you need to make sure that your web server is listening on port 443, and that the Security Group attached to your instances allow 443.

Keep in mind if you connect to your instances via IP then SSL will not work as it needs to be a domain name.